# Is it possible to use windows powershell or python to install and configure FTP on remote servers?

Tags: python, powershell, scripting

I was wondering if it is possible to write a script to remote into numerous servers to install FTP and then configure the setting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: definitely powershell, much simpler, if you are talking about windows, also you might consider using configuration management tools, like DSC, ansible, etc

Comment: Python has [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) to run commands on many servers (using SSH)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Or were you looking for someone to point you at/give you an already-written script?

Answer (score 0):

One pretty simple way of doing this would be to use ansible (python) https://github.com/bertvv/ansible-role-vsftpd that said ansible support for windows is a bit iffy.

Or maybe you could just use Python standard FTP lib to do what you need (it's already part of Python install)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html